# The data types varchar(max) and text are incompatible in the equal to operator. in SQL Server2005 how to solve?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
while(rs.next())
{
    String key=rs.getString(1);
    String val=rs.getString(2);       
    it=ar1.get(k).toString();
    if(it.trim().equals(key.trim()))   
    {
        val=val.substring(1);
        val=val+"1";
    }
    else
    {
        val=val.substring(1);
        val=val+"0";
    }

    st = con.prepareStatement("update win set seq=? where keyy=?");
    st.setString(1,val);
    st.setString(2,key); //here i am getting exception
    st.executeUpdate();
    st.close();
}
```

if i change data type of seq and keyy in table as text then it shows The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator

Comment: Get rid of your `<br>` tags. That's not how you format code on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm not going to start cleaning that up. Remove all the `<br />` tags and use the code formatting button: `{}`

Comment: sorry, I removed them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't messed with TEXT data type in forever.  But, leaving aside the questions about the wisdom of text "key" columns, you'll need to use `like`.  You cannot use standard comparison operators on `TEXT` and `NTEXT` (=,<=, etc).
You can leave out the wildcards, so it'll behave like an exact match.  So if your `keyy` column is text:

```
update win set seq=? where keyy like ?
```

BTW, `TEXT` and `NTEXT` have been deprecated for several versions of SQL Server, I'm sure that one of these days they're going to drop it.  You should probably look into converting to `CHAR` and `VARCHAR`.

Comment: i made seq and keyy data type as varchar(MAX) still it shows "varchar(MAX) and text are incompatible".when i made their data type text it shows "text and text are incompatible".what change should i made to either code or to table ?

Comment: You'll need to show us the DDL for the table you're querying.

Comment: changing to CHAR solved my problem . Thank You . will also try for comparison using like