# SELECT command: String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I'm trying to run the query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM tbl_MessageData 
WHERE data LIKE 'very_long_text'
```

I get the error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

The data field is defined to be `Text` and I succeeded inserting the "very_long_text" (the actual text is about 10000 chars long) into it.

Comment: `tex` is an archaic data type that is being removed from the product.  You should switch to `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: Why would you have a varchar parameter value in your where clause that is that large and especially with a `like` clause? This is what wild cards were made for. Truncate that value yourself after a certain point and add a % sign at the end. `WHERE data LIKE 'beginning_of_very_long_text%' `

Comment: How are you getting an error that's basically telling you "This doesn't fit here" on a select when you've already said you've successfully inserted the value into the data field?  This error is only thrown on an update or insert or potentially in your case because you're comparing a value that's too large for the actual field.  Please provide more information.

Comment: I changed it to VARCHAR(max) and the query only works (on SQL Server) if I change the LIKE to '='. Unfortunately, I can't do it because I execute the query with python and I get the error "The data types varchar(max) and text are incompatible in the equal to operator."

Answer (score 0):

You can only use 8000 chars in a query. Text data type will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server, instead use varchar or nvarchar.

You can see your column INFO:

```
 SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length    
 FROM information_schema.columns  
 WHERE table_name = 'YourTable'
```

You need to modify your column size like this:

```
 Alter table tbl_MessageData 
 ALTER COLUMN data VARCHAR(max) NOT NULL
```

Than you can try:

```
 SELECT id 
 FROM tbl_MessageData 
 WHERE data LIKE 'very_long_text'
```

Comment: I changed it to VARCHAR(max) and the query only works (on SQL Server) if I change the LIKE to '='. Unfortunately, I can't do it because I execute the query with python and I get the error "The data types varchar(max) and text are incompatible in the equal to operator."

Comment: @ShaniGamrian http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180766/the-data-types-varcharmax-and-text-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator

Comment: I tried using LIKE and it didn't work with very long strings (even after changing to VARCHAR). Besides, I'm not using Text anymore so I don't understand why I'm even getting this error.